# RODBC sqlSave to SQL Server fails when one column is POSIXct to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, rodbc

Data.table with one POSIXct column to save to SQL Server using RODBC::sqlSave.
When saving with just this column and one other column, specifying varTypes=c(lastrun='datetime') this saves fine.  But if I include an additional column we get SQL Server error:

> An invalid tabular data stream (TDS) collation was encountered.

Where do I need to look to overcome this block?

See reprex below:

```r
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
c_sr <- data.table(ID = as.integer(c(1,2)), 
                   lastrun = as.POSIXct(c('2022-10-21 10:11:13', '2022-10-21 11:10:09')), 
                   runby=c(NA_character_, 'ABC'), 
                   currentrun = c('N','Y'))

c_chan <- RODBC::odbcConnect('xopt_process')
#First example, no datetime column - SUCCESS
RODBC::sqlSave(c_chan, c_sr[,.(ID, runby)], 'tmp01', rownames = FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
#> Query: CREATE TABLE "tmp01"  ("ID" int, "runby" varchar(255))
#> Query: INSERT INTO "tmp01" ( "ID", "runby" ) VALUES ( ?,? )
#> Binding: 'ID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
#> Binding: 'runby' DataType 12, ColSize 255
#> Parameters:
#> no: 1: ID 1/***/no: 2: runby NA/***/
#> no: 1: ID 2/***/no: 2: runby ABC/***/

#Second example, ID + datetime column - SUCCESS
RODBC::sqlSave(c_chan, c_sr[,.(ID, lastrun)], 'tmp02', varTypes=c(lastrun='datetime'), rownames = FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
#> Query: CREATE TABLE "tmp02"  ("ID" int, "lastrun" datetime)
#> Query: INSERT INTO "tmp02" ( "ID", "lastrun" ) VALUES ( ?,? )
#> Binding: 'ID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
#> Binding: 'lastrun' DataType 93, ColSize 23
#> Parameters:
#> no: 1: ID 1/***/no: 2: lastrun 2022-10-21 10:11:13/***/
#> no: 1: ID 2/***/no: 2: lastrun 2022-10-21 11:10:09/***/

#Third example, ID + datetime column + additional column - FAIL
RODBC::sqlSave(c_chan, c_sr[,.(ID, lastrun, currentrun)], 'tmp03', varTypes=c(lastrun='datetime'), rownames = FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
#> Query: CREATE TABLE "tmp03"  ("ID" int, "lastrun" datetime, "currentrun" varchar(255))
#> Query: INSERT INTO "tmp03" ( "ID", "lastrun", "currentrun" ) VALUES ( ?,?,? )
#> Binding: 'ID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
#> Binding: 'lastrun' DataType 93, ColSize 23
#> Binding: 'currentrun' DataType 12, ColSize 255
#> Parameters:
#> no: 1: ID 1/***/no: 2: lastrun 2022-10-21 10:11:13/***/no: 3: currentrun N/***/
#> Error in RODBC::sqlSave(c_chan, c_sr[, .(ID, lastrun, currentrun)], "tmp03", : [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
#> 42000 4012 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An invalid tabular data stream (TDS) collation was encountered.

#Fourth example, all except datetime column - SUCCESS
RODBC::sqlSave(c_chan, c_sr[,.(ID, runby, currentrun)], 'tmp04', rownames = FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
#> Query: CREATE TABLE "tmp04"  ("ID" int, "runby" varchar(255), "currentrun" varchar(255))
#> Query: INSERT INTO "tmp04" ( "ID", "runby", "currentrun" ) VALUES ( ?,?,? )
#> Binding: 'ID' DataType 4, ColSize 10
#> Binding: 'runby' DataType 12, ColSize 255
#> Binding: 'currentrun' DataType 12, ColSize 255
#> Parameters:
#> no: 1: ID 1/***/no: 2: runby NA/***/no: 3: currentrun N/***/
#> no: 1: ID 2/***/no: 2: runby ABC/***/no: 3: currentrun Y/***/

RODBC::sqlDrop(c_chan, 'tmp04')
RODBC::sqlDrop(c_chan, 'tmp03')
RODBC::sqlDrop(c_chan, 'tmp02')
RODBC::sqlDrop(c_chan, 'tmp01')
RODBC::odbcClose(c_chan)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This error appears to occur only if there is a character column following the datetime column.  No problem if one or more datetime columns are at the end, or if there is an integer column following. SQL Server 2019, RODBC 1.3-19, odbc driver 17 for MS SQL.

Comment: Collation is related to grouping, sorting and transformation of Unicode code points (characters) to subsets of code points (characters) that make up code pages. If you only see this error when there's a character/string column included then it sounds like your ODBC DSN isn't configured correctly. How have you set that up?

Comment: Each of the columns can be loaded on their own.  It is only when a character column follows the datetime column that the error occurs.  If I provide the columns in a different order then it works.  So it doesn't appear to be to do with the DSN configuration. It appears that there is a disconnect between odbc and SQL Server with respect to how the data is passed to SQL.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It looks like you are on to something there.  It appears that by default ODBC Data Source Administrator set 'Perform translation for character data' to ON.  When I switch this OFF then the error goes away.
I don't know what the wider implications of switching this off are. 
I do have some unicode data, but not in use in this example.